# Can I rotate patterns?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So I scanned some QR codes after getting the big sewing machine from Able and I have a corner piece for a walkway I want to build. The only problem is the it's a top left corner piece and the QR code offered no other corner pieces. Is there a way to rotate this?

Comment: Isn't how the pattern falls based on how you're standing when you drop it? I could be wrong, can't test it now, but furniture works that way

Comment: @BenBrocka Unfortunately, no, all patterns are dropped in a fixed position. :(

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there's no way to rotate patterns. Unlike furniture, which will drop in a certain direction based on where you're facing, patterns do not behave this way. They are always placed in a fixed position.

If you have a pattern that's not facing the direction you want it to, your only option is to either remake it if it's yours, or delete it if it is not, as you can't redesign patterns made by other people. Alternatively, you could also make a new, rotated pattern based off of the design of the existing piece by looking at it which, while somewhat tedious, would work for your purposes.

Answer (score -3):

No, you can't rotate patterns on the ground. However you can find paths [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=animal%20crossing%20new%20leaf%20path&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=VQiVU6qEJZLwoATBlYGYDw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1600&bih=799#imgdii=_) that look rotated

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the existing answer...

Comment: ok I'll edit it

Comment: A google link is just barely above "not helpful at all".  Please at least link to something more relevant, such as a wiki.